# Login failed for user 'sa' on MAC Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure

So I am new to the Azure Data Studio and I am trying to make a new connection. I tried the method below:

[The method I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720236/how-to-connect-sql-server-on-mac)

My password adheres to the rules: "at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols" and I followed the code strictly. However, when I input the values, the Azure is giving me " error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)." What are some simple steps I can perform to check what went wrong? How do I allow the remote access?

Comment: Does your password use special characters like `$`?

Comment: There are several methods listed on the linked page. Questions should be self-contained so that we don't have to open other pages to guess what might be your issue. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70587289/edit) your question to  spell out the specific method you tried from the other page - as text.

Comment: what server name are you entering to log in?